# Unit Tests for iOS Libraries and Xamarin Studio's Test Runner

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin-studio

I want to use a Xamarin.iOS Library Project:

[image]

And within this project I want to add unit tests (currently with nunit, but xunit would be fine, too).

> I do **not** want to run them on the device/simulator (which is possible with the "Unit Test App" project template). **I want those tests to be executed by the native test runner within XS.**

Is there any hack known to get this to work?

(Actually those tests run just fine with nunit in Visual Studio, when the Xamarin.iOS reference is copied locally on every build, but on Mono/XS it doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: Scroll down to `Other` and under the `.Net` section there is a project template for `NUnit Library Project`

Comment: Which can't reference an iOS Library Project.

Comment: If you are referencing a native framework library in it then no, if you have methods in your device dependent library that you want to test that are not device dependent move them to a separate PCL/.NetStandard library

Comment: No, that is no option here.